# How can I force points in a list to have distinct x values?

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a list of points that may be used for linear interpolation using `Interpolation` and need to ensure that no two points have the same $x$ value, since, if they do, `Interpolation` reports errors:

[image]

Ideally I'd like to simply tweak such points just enough, that their control points don't shift visibly, but that they satisfy `Interpolation` (e.g. by adding a very small number to one of the offending points).

Alternatively, perhaps a different *Mathematica* interpolation function or different options for `Interpolation` avoid this error.

I've tried randomizing the points a bit, using various methods, but I get strange behavior, including briefly jagged plots (e.g. when changing settings for `iorder`) and eventual unresponsiveness of the control points (they just won't move).

```
Manipulate[
 (*pts = MapAt[# + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 10^-4]] &, 
   pts, -1];*)
 (*pts={RandomReal[{#[[1]]-.0001,#[[1]]+.0001}],#[[2]]}&/@pts;*)    
 Plot[Interpolation[Prepend[pts, {0, 0}], InterpolationOrder -> iorder][x], {x, 0, 1}],
 {{pts, {{.2, .1}, {.4, .2}, {.6, .3}, {.8, .25}, {1, 0}}}, Locator},
 {{iorder, 3, "InterpolationOrder"}, Range[3], SetterBar}]
```

In context, I switch among even more curve fitting methods (e.g. Bezier, etc.), so dropping points is not an option, nor is moving them perceptibly, or skipping them.

Comment: Why not just add a tiny amount of random floating point error to *all* coordinates?

Comment: @whuber: I'm not sure how to do that, if I precede the plot with something like `pts = {RandomReal[{#[[1]] - .0001, #[[1]] + .0001}], #[[2]]} & /@ pts;`, I get a wobbly plot.

Comment: what about `DeleteDuplicates`?

Comment: @chris: No dropping, skipping or (perceptibly) moving of points. All the control points need to pretty much seem to stay where there are. They can "stick" of shift a tiny amount if that's the only way, but removing them is definitely out.

Comment: I don't know what the structure of `points` is intended to be, so I'll give you an inefficient generic solution to jitter all the coordinates: `MapAt[# + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 10^-4]] &, points,  -1]`. Use a uniform distribution to limit the amount of jittering if you like and change the `10^-4` to suit your tastes. Generalizations of this approach will jitter only the x-coordinates. The idea here is to avoid looking for duplicates altogether. And if you're willing to change *some* coordinates, arguably it's best to change them *all* in the same fashion.

Comment: @whuber: See edit, which incorporates a version of randomization.

Comment: Yes: You should expect bizarre behavior with many interpolators when they are presented with close-by points. *Any* interpolator that attempts to put a curve exactly through all points will run into trouble: that's why duplicates are not allowed! You say you want *linear* interpolation: perhaps you could elaborate on that a little, because it sounds like you might not be doing exactly the kind of calculation you had hoped to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your points are in order, then you could just use a rule:

```
rule = {before___, {x_, y1_}, {x_, y2_}, after___} -> 
       {before, {x, y1}, {x + tweak, y2}, after}
```

Then apply with repeated replacement:

```
pts //. rule
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 7):

It seems that interpolation in *two* dimensions is desired.  To do so, interpolate the x- and y-coordinates separately and plot the curve parametrically:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{f = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> iorder] & /@ 
             Transpose[Prepend[pts, {0, 0}]]},
  ParametricPlot[Through[f[x]], {x, 1, Length[pts]+1}, PlotRange -> {Full, Full}]],
 {{pts, {{.2, .1}, {.4, .2}, {.6, .3}, {.8, .25}, {1, 0}}}, Locator},
 {{iorder, 3, "InterpolationOrder"}, Range[3]}]
```

[image: Plot]

Now it does not matter that some of the x-coordinates may have been duplicated.

Comment: "...interpolate the $x$- and $y$-coordinates separately and plot the curve parametrically." - in that regard, one might consider using something like [centripetal parametrization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11659) for the purpose...

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for that reference.