# Get 2d corner coordinates / layout using edge detection

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm new to Mathematica but I found an interesting usage of it:
I'm programming a 2D game, with a top-view, where I'd like to have the edge
coordinates of the walls. EdgeDetection delivers me quite a good result:

[image: The level background]
[image: Edge detection on the background]

[In this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/generating-x-y-coordinates-for-an-edge-detection), I saw a really impressing example of getting picture points
into a (even) 3D plot. I found `PixelValuePositions[background, 1]` which delivers me all white pixels. However, I really don't understand how to get the 4 corners of after running `EdgeDetect` and creating a immense list of white pixels.

How can I (iterate) through the points, to get the 4 corners every wall has?

**Update 1:**

I view walls as simple rectangular shapes, given by two corners.
The expected results are for each "wall rectangle" two points that define
the rectangle (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

[image: Example picture]

Is it possible to get an output just like:

```
x1 y1 x2 y2
x1 y1 x2 y2
```

this means, just "printing out" the coordinates of a rectangle on a line,
then give the next rectangle on a new line?

**Update 2:**

As s.s.o mentioned, it seems to be quite related to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t).
The accepted answer uses `ComponentMeasurements`, but I simply don't get it
how it works and if it does for my situation, too.

Comment: This answer should be adaptable for your task: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4358/131

Comment: @YvesKlett Do you think I need to use `MorphologicalGraph` as well?

Comment: Not neccessarily, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Mathematica stops calculating, before I can see a result. Might this be, because (at the moment) I only have a trial version of Mathematica 10?

Comment: Probably not. Cannot try right now. Can you specify what you mean by 4 corners of each wall?  Perhaps by sketching which points you are after...

Comment: I see the "Wall" as a simple rectangle with 4 corners. I just noticed, the command works, and `EdgeList[]` gives me a Graph like `1-1, 1-6, 2-5, 3-5, 4-6, 5-6`. I don't know what this means :/

Comment: you should see the post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM4LS.png";
img = MorphologicalBinarize@Import[url];
cornerslist = ImageCorners[img];

Show[
 img2,
 ListPlot[
  {
   cornerslist
   }
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  , PlotMarkers -> Automatic
  ]
 ]
```

> [image]

```
rectcorner = Join[
  MinimalBy[cornerslist, First, 2],
  MaximalBy[cornerslist, First, 2]
  ]
```

> ```
> {{78.5, 46.5}, {79.5, 314.5}, {554.5, 311.5}, {554.5, 48.5}}
> ```

```
Show[
 img,
 Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[0.3], Polygon[rectcorner]}],
 ListPlot[rectcorner], PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]

```
lines = ImageLines[EdgeDetect[img]];
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ lines}]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Wow, this is very impressive! If I follow your code and at the end, just type `lines`, I get a list of coordinates. These are coordinates you used to draw the orange lines on top of the image, aren't they? However, I'd like to get the coordinates of every wall segment. If you have a look at the left room at the bottom, you can see that the little wall forming the door, doesn't get recognized. Your approach is pretty close to my expected results!

Comment: @pentix look at the first lines where `cornerslist` is defined.

Comment: @pentix There are also parameters you can play with (see the documentation.  For example: `lines = ImageLines[EdgeDetect[img], 0.05, 0.005]; Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line@Select[lines, Min@Abs@Differences@# < 3 &]}]]`, where `Select` picks out lines whose difference in x or difference in y is less than 3 pixels.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks a lot! I get to same result, and it works so far. However, the last part what I'm looking for. (I'm sorry for noticing this that late!) I updated the original question, please have a look at it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @pentix you are moving the goal post! :) You need to explain better what do you mean with the 4 points per wall. Walls with thickness and shared regions with other walls makes this ambiguous.

Comment: @rhermans I know, this is kind of embarassing, I'm incredibly sorry :/ Let's call the wall "the greatest rectangle that covers the part of the wall". In the end, it doesn't really matter if the coordinates intersect (= the walls have shared regions), but there should be a rectangle for every wall. Thank you ;)