# Smoothen the curve found by EdgeDetect

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, filtering

It seems that curves found by `EdgeDetect` always persist $C^{0}$ continuity only. Consider the following example:

```
l = 10; r = Pi/2;
(*Create an image of a smooth curve *)
pic = Rasterize@Plot[ArcTan[x], {x, -l, l}, Filling -> Bottom, Axes -> None, 
                                            PlotRangePadding -> None,PlotRange -> r];

(* Recover data points from the image *)
data = ImageValuePositions[Thinning@EdgeDetect@Binarize@pic, 1];

(* Create a interpolating function with the points *)
{w, h} = ImageDimensions@pic;
trf = Last@FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {0, r}, {l, 0}}, 
                                  {{w/2, h/2}, {w/2, h}, {w, h/2}}];
func = Interpolation[DeleteDuplicates[trf /@ data, First@# == First@#2 &]];

{{lb, rb}} = func["Domain"]
(* Check the derivatives of func *)
Plot[{ArcTan'[x], func'[x]}, {x, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

As one can see, the recovered solution is far from the analytic one, oscillating disastrously, full of noise, in a word, bad. So the question is, with what kind of postprocessing can I get a smooth ($C^{1}$ continuity, at least) and distortionless interpolating curve? I've played with `GaussianFilter` and `LowpassFilter` for a while but the result isn't great.

Comment: I had to add `ImagePadding -> None` to your `Plot` to get the same result in Mathematica 10.2

Comment: @nikie That sounds interesting, in v9 when `Axes->None` is set, `ImagePadding->All` (I think this is the default setting) and `ImagePadding->None` gives the same result. Maybe it's worth  asking another question for this?

Comment: In v10, I see a thin white border without `ImagePadding->None`, and `EdgeDetect` finds another set of edges at the bottom and at the right. Some subtle change due to the new default themes, perhaps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a "natural" image, you'd look at each edge pixel in, use some approximation (e.g. 2nd order polynomial) of the gradients above/below that pixel and calculate the sub-pixel position of the steepest gradient.

But in your case, all `EdgeDetect` gets to work on is a binary image, and any the potential anti aliasing sub-pixel information is lost. So the best you can probably do is find a curve that is as smooth as possible, while still less than 0.5 pixel from the discrete pixel values `EdgeDetect` found. You can do that using constrained optimization.

Reusing code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46862/242):

```
xValues = Array[# &, w, func["Domain"]];
discreteValues = func[xValues];

n = Length[discreteValues];
vars = Array[y, n];
maxDist = 0.5 Norm[trf[{0, 0}] - trf[{0, 1}]];
```

Here are the optimization objectives: find a list of values `y[1]`..`y[n]` s.t. the distance to the original values `discreteValues[i]` is below 0.5 pixels and smoothness as small as possible:

```
constraints = 
  Array[discreteValues[[#]] - maxDist <= y[#] <= 
     discreteValues[[#]] + maxDist &, n];
smoothness = Total[Differences[vars, 2]^2];
startValues = Array[{y[#], discreteValues[[#]]} &, n];
{fit, sol} = 
  FindMinimum[{smoothness, constraints}, startValues, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10];
smoothedValues = (vars /. sol);
```

Here's a graphic visualization of the constraints and the results:

```
zoomStartIdx = 250;
Row[{
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xValues, smoothedValues}], ImageSize -> 600,
    PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Gray, Dashed}], Transparent, 
     Rectangle @@ (Transpose[{xValues, 
          smoothedValues}][[{zoomStartIdx, -1}]])}],
  Show[
   ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{xValues, discreteValues - maxDist}], 
      Transpose[{xValues, discreteValues + maxDist}]}[[All, 
     zoomStartIdx ;;]],
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thin], ImageSize -> 600],
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xValues, smoothedValues}], 
    PlotStyle -> Orange, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]],
  LineLegend[{Orange, Blue}, {"Smoothed curve", "Constraints"}]
  }]
```

[image]
Using (mostly) your code to display the result

```
(*Create a interpolating function with the points*)
{w, h} = ImageDimensions@pic;
funcSmooth = Interpolation[Transpose[{xValues, smoothedValues}]];

{{lb, rb}} = funcSmooth["Domain"];
(*Check the derivatives of func*)
Plot[{ArcTan'[x], funcSmooth'[x]}, {x, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems that FindMinimum is improved (?) in v10.2, in v9 `AccuracyGoal -> 10` only makes things worse, but the result without `AccuracyGoal` isn't bad anyway.

Comment: @nikie Could you please give an example of using of the anti-aliasing sub-pixel information for recovering data from a raster plot with maximum exactness possible? Data recovering is a very common task but usually it is made through crude binarization of the original anti-aliased image. It would be very valuable to have an example of more advanced approach.