# Convex and concave regions of a closed curve

Tags: graphics, image-processing

A few days ago, in *Mathematica*'s help, I saw a function for recognizing if a closed curve has a positive or negative radius (convex or concave) like in the picture I found on the web, but without the lines!

[image]

I cannot find the help example anymore. Could someone please tell me what I might have been looking at?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95425/242